# Limit of Root: Shifted

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

It is a well known fact that:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$$
But what about the shifted one up:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{n}=1$$
And what about the shifted one down:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}=1$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use the fact that $\sqrt[n]{n}>\sqrt[n+1]{n}>1$, in order to conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{n}=1$

As to the other question you added:

You can use the fact that $\forall p\exists q>p:\sqrt[p]{p}>\sqrt[q]{q+1}>1$, and conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n+1}=1$

Comment: Cool thx and what about shifted one down (see edited question)

Comment: Mhh but you cannot deduce the last since: $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n b_n,\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\text{ exist}\nRightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\text{ exists}$

Comment: @Freeze_S: I agree, but I did the exact opposite in this case. If to take your notation, then I did $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n$ exists $\implies\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_nb_n$ exists.

Comment: Yes so I added your answer according to this if u don't mind

Comment: @Freeze_S: I do mind, actually, because what you wrote has got nothing to do with my answer. I might as well remove it all together, because I don't see how $\sqrt[n]{n}\sqrt[n]{n}$ is helpful here.

Comment: @Freeze_S: I simplified the answer to the second question. Please see updated answer.

Comment: Mhh that's not enough either since it has to hold for almost all: $a_n\leq b_n$

Comment: It helps since $1<\sqrt[n]{n+1}<\sqrt[n]{n}\sqrt[n]{n}\to 1$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(n) = \sqrt[n+1]{n} = n^{1/(n + 1)}$. Then

$$\ln f(n) = \frac{\ln n}{n + 1} \to 0$$

as $n \to \infty$, so $f(n) \to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

One can use the same proof. But there is no need to go back to basics, since $$n^{1/(n+1)}=(n+1)^{1/(n+1)} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{1/(n+1)},$$
and it is clear that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{1/(n+1)}=1.$$