# Shifting Sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

**Disclaimer**

This thread is meant to record.
*(For more details see: [Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))*

For jeopardy it is written as question anyway. Have fun! :)

**Problem**

Mostly well-known it holds:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{k+1}$$
That is due to the estimate :
$$\sqrt[k]{k}\leq\sqrt[k]{k+1}\leq\sqrt[k]{2k}$$
*(See thread on: [Shifted Root](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/777486/79762))*

Now, can it happen that shifts have effect:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}a(k,k)\neq\lim_{k\to\infty}a(k,k+1)$$
*(Note that the sequence must have two arguments.)*

Comment: In order to specify a limit, you need to specify where $k$ is approaching, e.g. $\lim_{k\to \infty}$ or $\lim_{k\to 0}$ or etc.

Comment: @BenMillwood: I added it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can happen!

Consider the sequence:
$$a(k,l):=k-l$$
Then shifting has effect:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}k-k=0\neq1=\lim_{k\to\infty}(k+1)-k$$